# How can I store sql table row count in a string variable?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to store the result of query string

```
q = "select count(*) from test" (asp.net c#)
```

in a string variable so that I can display the count on a label on button click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    int RecordCount;
    RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
   string myString =  RecordCount.ToString();
```

Comment: Will this work?
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string s = "select count(*) from ExcelTable";
        string r = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch { }
        int RecordCount;
        RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        r = RecordCount.ToString();
        Label1.Text = r;
    }

Comment: The value of ExecuteScalar can be null, you should for that before converting

Comment: ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The value of [ExecuteScalar can be null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), make sure you check for null

```
int RecordCount = 0;
object retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(retVal != null)
    RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```